# how to get a list from C# code into a list in python

Tags: c#, python

I have a C# DLL that I am calling in python and one of its methods returns what should be like a list `<system.Double[]>`

this code works

```
data =[0,1]
ch=['VCC_CORE0','VCCSFR']
data[0],data[1] = myDaqControl.SpyMulti(ch)
```

but I am trying to make it dynamic don't want to add the list arguments at the start
because in this example I have ch = 2 variables but next time it can be 5 or 10

so typing `data[0],data[1].....` doesn't make sense

doing `data =  myDaqControl.SpyMulti(ch)` doesn't work and I get from interpreter is:

```
<System.Double[] object>
```

i found out the the C# code should be returning an Array

additional code priore to what i mentioned

```
import clr
import sys
import timeit
import time


Channel ='Iin_P1'
ConfigFile='c:\NiDaq_spy.xml'

start_time = time.time()
sys.path.append(r'C:\daq\Bin')
clr.AddReference('DaqBase.Factory')
from Daq import DaqControlFactory
from Daq import IDaqControl
myDaqControl = DaqControlFactory.GetDaqControl("NiDaq")
```

Answer (score 0):

`data = myDaqControl.SpyMulti(ch)` does return more or less what you want - an array of doubles. You  only need to turn it into a list explicitly if you want to use it as one, but I suspect you might be able to just use it directly. Try doing that.

You might be able to do this:

```
data = list(myDaqControl.SpyMulti(ch))
```

or there might be some method of the array or another function that does it. Without knowing which library you are using it is difficult to tell.

Failing that, try this:

```
data = [item for item in myDaqControl.SpyMulti(ch)]
```

or the non-list-comprehension equivalent:

```
data = []
for item in data:
    data.append(item)
```

Comment: @user2740068 What is the C# DLL called?

Comment: DaqBase.Factory.dll a setup program that was created from national instruments daqmx dll's